# How does a cursor used by a RemoteViewService get deactivated

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-appwidget

I get ACRA exception reports from some users that the cursor which supplies data to my appwidget (`RemoteViewService`) is deactivated/closed.  It never happens to me in person, but it happens enough where it's a bit of an issue.

Here's the code to my RemoteViewService:

```
    public static class ListItemService extends RemoteViewsService {

        public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(final Intent intent) {

            return new RemoteViewsFactory() {

                private MyCursor cursor;

                public void onCreate() {
                    // Nothing
                }

                public synchronized void onDestroy() {
                    if (this.cursor != null)
                        this.cursor.close();
                }

                public synchronized RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
                      // Here I read from the cursor and it crashes with
                      // the stack trace below
                }

                public int getCount() {
                      return ((this.cursor != null) ? this.cursor.getCount() : 0);
                }

                public int getViewTypeCount() {
                    return 1;
                }

                public boolean hasStableIds() {
                    return true;
                }

                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
                    return null;
                }

                public synchronized void onDataSetChanged()
                {
                    if (this.cursor != null)
                        this.cursor.close();

                    this.cursor = getApplicationCntext().getContentResolver().query(myUri, null, null, null, null);
                }
            };
```

The stack trace varies from platform version to platform version.  For example, I get the following on 4.0.3:

```
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
```

On 2.3, I get a:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out who or what closes the cursor on me, other than from `onDestroy()` and `onDataSetChanged()`.  Some users had reported that they weren't actively working with app when the crash happened.

I suspected maybe multiple calls to the ContentProvider return the same cursor and when I display my UI which uses the same query, they step on each other.  But this doesn't appear to be the case as the cursor objects are different.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like a sync issue between multiple threads, one closing the previous cursor and one immediately accessing it thereafter.

You may want to consider closing the cursor right when you first can, such as a onPause event.

Also - you can add a safety precaution as checking cursor.isClosed() before you access it again. You can also add some synchronisation to your code.

A helper method that fetches the new cursor with a local var and only once it's done, replaces the previous one and closes it may be a quicker solution in the meantime.

From [AOSP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) doc;

> This interface provides random read-write access to the result set
>   returned by a database query. Cursor implementations are not required
>   to be synchronized so code using a Cursor from multiple threads should
>   perform its own synchronization when using the Cursor.

From [Content provider basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html),

> The ContentResolver.query() client method always returns a Cursor containing the columns specified by the query's projection for the rows that match the query's selection criteria. A Cursor object provides random read access to the rows and columns it contains. Using Cursor methods, you can iterate over the rows in the results, determine the data type of each column, get the data out of a column, and examine other properties of the results. Some Cursor implementations automatically update the object when the provider's data changes, or trigger methods in an observer object when the Cursor changes, or both.

Comment: I gave you the bounty -- but I am not sure if this is really the issue, so I didn't "accept" the answer.  Unless the cursor returned by query() is somehow backed by the same underlying database object, I don't know how they can step on each other's toes.  The returned Java objects are different -- I verified this by printing their hashCode().

This is strictly an issue if I use a ContentProvider.  If I query the database directly with the SqlLite objects, I don't get this behavior.  I would be happy to post my ContentProvider code if that helps.

Comment: Well, your implementation using the cursor is a little simplistic and it looks like the query should also be made on a different thread in any case, even if we did want to stick with it. Cursors were a little broken in the days where you had to let activities manage them for you and before CursorLoader was introduced. Take a look at  https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex and let me know if it helps as it should provide you with all the capabilities you need and more. If that is too much, there are simpler back ported ideas of implementing a simple cursor loader, which basically lets it b

Comment: The code I listed for a scrollable AppWidget, not for an Activity.  I basically took the example from the docs.  Once again, if I replace the ContentProvider provided cursor with one directly created from the database, I don't get a problem.

Comment: I understood that, but was just mentioning some cursor history, for general knowledge. Basically it's the same issue. If you solved it in another way, you can post your own solution and accept it so that other people get your idea too.

Comment: I didn't solve it.  I would like to use a ContentProvider query, but I am forced to use a direct database query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `this.cursor = null` on `onDestory()` method

```
public synchronized void onDestroy() {
    if (this.cursor != null){
        this.cursor.close();
        this.cursor = null
    }
}
```